# JQuery click event not workiong on Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm developing a site using Spring Boot. I've a list of elements and each element have a link. I want to call a javascript function when the links are pressed.
I have this code

```html
<div class="col-sm-4" th:each="product : ${productsList}">
  <!-- Code... -->
  <a th:id="${'buyButton' + product.id}" <!-- rest of attributes -->></a>
  <!-- More code... -->
  <script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
      console.log("Log1");
      $("#buyButton[[${product.id}]]").click(function() {
        console.log("Log2");
      });
    /*]]>*/
  </script>
</div>
```

productsList have 5 elements, so when I load the page, it prints "Log1" five times, but when I click on the links, the function that prints "Log2" doesn't work.

Can anyone help me. I'm going crazy...

Comment: Can you have a look at the JavaScript code in the browser how this was rendered by thymeleaf?

Comment: Yes. I check it and I can see the script block. The selectors are OK #buyButton1, #buyButton2, etc... It isn't a thymeleaf parse error. It's so strange.

Comment: I also record the actions at network tab, but the click event doesn't shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a common class i.e. `productBuyButton` to the anchor element and the attach event handler using Class Selector `$('.ClassName')`

```
<div class="col-sm-4" th:each="product : ${productsList}">
  <!-- Code... -->
  <a class="productBuyButton" th:id="${'buyButton' + product.id}" <!-- rest of attributes -->></a>
  <!-- More code... -->

</div>

<script th:inline="javascript">
      $(".productBuyButton").click(function() {
        console.log(this.id);
        //Here `this` refers to element which invoked the event handler
      });
</script>
```

---

if you want to persist existing code the change the selector to `$('#buyButton${product.id}')`